# Dynamically set css transform before transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to simulate a mouse animation.  I would like to dynamically set the position, then move it with a css transition.  So far I am able to get a program that moves the mouse.  However, I am having trouble setting the initial position dynamically with javascript.  My code looks like this:

Here is the CSS

```
.cursorDiv {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: translate(0px,0px);
  transition: 2s ease;
}

.cursorDivMoved {
  transform: translate(100px,200px);
}
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var cursorDiv = document.createElement("img");
cursorDiv.className = "cursorDiv";
cursorDiv.src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-                    style/512/cursor.png";
document.body.appendChild(cursorDiv);

setTimeout(function() {
  $(".cursorDiv").toggleClass("cursorDivMoved");
}, 1000);

//cursorDiv.style.transform="translate(100px,50px)";
```

When I run this it works fine.  However, when I try to change the initial position with javascript (uncomment last line), then the transition doesn't occur anymore.

Here is a Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/fmt1rbsy/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you programmatically set the `style.transform` property directly on your element (which you need if you want to move it to an arbitrary position through JS), it will override any `transform` specified in classes. Hence adding `"cursorDivMoved"` class later on does not transform (translate / move) it.

You have to continue moving it by specifying its `style.transform` property, or simply remove it: `cursorDiv.style.transform = null`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fmt1rbsy/9/

You may also want to have the very first `translate` being transitioned. In that case, you have to wait for the browser to make an initial layout with your element at its start position, otherwise it will see no transition (it will see it directly **after** the transform is applied, i.e. at its final position). You can either:

- Use a small (but non zero) `setTimeout` to give some time for the browser to do its initial layout.
- Force a browser layout by trying to access some property that require the browser to compute the page layout (e.g. `document.body.offsetWidth`).
- Use 2 nested `requestAnimationFrame`'s before applying your `transform`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fmt1rbsy/8/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Tell me if it can be improved. Open your console and change the class name to `cursorDivMoved`.

```js
var cursorDiv = document.createElement("img");
cursorDiv.className = "cursorDiv";
cursorDiv.id = 'cursorDiv';
cursorDiv.src = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/cursor.png";
document.body.appendChild(cursorDiv);
```

```css
#cursorDiv {
width:30px;
height:30px;
-o-transition: 2s ease;
-moz-transition: 2s ease;
-webkit-transition: 2s ease;
-ms-transition: 2s ease;
transition: 2s ease;
}
.cursorDivMoved {
-o-transform:translate(100px, 200px);
-moz-transform:translate(100px, 200px);
-webkit-transform:translate(100px, 200px);
-ms-transform:translate(100px, 200px);
transform:translate(100px, 200px);
}
```

Comment: What I want to do is dynamically set the initial and final positions of the cursor using javascript.

Comment: Ok, I will revise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define initial postion (x,y), and then when user click the position will increase and set to the 'cursorDiv', such as:

```
var cursorDiv = document.createElement("img");
cursorDiv.className = "cursorDiv";
cursorDiv.src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/512/cursor.png";
document.body.appendChild(cursorDiv);
var x = 100, y = 50;
setTimeout(function() {
  cursorDiv.style.transform="translate(100px,50px)";
}, 1000);

$(document).click(function () {
    x+= 20;
            y += 50;
    var str = "translate(" + x + "px," + y + "px)";
    cursorDiv.style.transform=str;
        });
```

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/phuongtotti/snt9b275/)